# Flutter Firebase notification onlunch is not working

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, android-notifications, firebase-notifications

I am using FCM service in my flutter app for push notification. onMessage and onResume are working, the problem is when I remove my app from the recent apps list. I successfully get a push notification when my app is killed but the problem is when I click on it I am not getting the access of the data payload in my flutter code. callerInfo is not being set.
Notifications are not getting delivered when the app is swiped from the background(kill mode).

JSON file

```
  {
    "notification": {
        "title": "bla bla",
        "body"  : "bla bla",
        "icon":"incoming_call",
        "color": "#008080",
        "click_action":"FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK",
        "tag" : "call"
    },

    "data": {
        "caller":"caller1",
        "image":"
    },
    "to":"#token",

    "android":{
      "priority":"high"
    }

}
```

flutter config code in the initState() {}

```
  _configureFireBaseListeners(){
    _firebaseMessaging.configure(
      onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async{
        //_setMessage(message);
        print("onMessage: $message");
      },
      onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async{
        //_setMessage(message);
        print("onLaunch: $message");
        setState((){
          _isCall=message['data']['status'];
          callerInfo = message['data'];
        });
      },
      onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async{
        //_setMessage(message);
        print("onResume: $message");
        setState((){
          _isCall=message['data']['status'];
          callerInfo = message['data'];
        });
      },
    );
  }
```

Comment: did you get solutions?